# htaccess rewrite rule to alternative subfolder / url structure

Tags: .htaccess

I need some assistance to rewrite/redirect people with the following urls.

mydomain.com/client/index.php

to

mydomain.com/client-area/?ccce=index

So the name of the php file will be added to the ?ccce=XXXXX part of the other subfolder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the .htaccess in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^client/([^/]+)\.php$ /client-area/?ccce=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thats great will try that shortly.

Is there a way to omit one specific page (the admin area) from the rewrite rule?

So ignore when it is /client/admin but rewrite all the others?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/client/admin` or a negative look-ahead (`(?!admin)`) before the capture group.